# How to compare Profile2 field with PCP percentage in drupal 7 while creating Rule?

Tags: 7, users, rules

I am using Rules, PCP & Profile2 Module in drupal 7. I want to send mail to those user whose profile is <60%, how to add condition for sending mail? How can i compare the profile2 field with pcp %. I already created a Event & Action. Problem in add contion. Please help. Thanks

[image]

I want condition like this i.e. $complete_profile<60. If by using php code then how can i implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Rules Integration for D7 version issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1489350) in Profile Complete Percent issue queue. Only condition they implemented is, it seems, *"User profile is completed"*.

[image: Screenshot of conditions]

Maybe there are additional conditions now. Open this window and see. If condition you want is lacking, you will need to either file a feature request for PCP, or write own custom module, clone *"User profile is completed"* in it, changing name and switching from `=100%` (or how they actually implemented it) to `<60%`.

Comment: okk it mean that to apply this condition we need to create custom module.

Comment: @samzha probably yes.

Comment: If I want to send mail in every 7 days i.e "please login site, you are not logged in since 7 days", only if that user has not logged in since 7 days. Without checking there profile completion. @Molot

Comment: If that's a new question, please ask it as new question.